# need Help on XSLT logic

Tags: xml, xslt

Can anyone please help me to get the XSLT logic over here.I have explained the requirement as comments in the output.please find the below is the output and input.

input:

```
    <OutputParameters>

  <OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL>
    <OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL_ITEM>
    <SLevel1>1</SLevel1>
    <SLevel1>S</SLevel1>
      <DELIVERY_ID>2334356776</DELIVERY_ID>
      <ORDER_SHIP_CODE_EXT>3467</ORDER_SHIP_CODE_EXT>
      <CUSTOMER_NUMBER>4838</CUSTOMER_NUMBER>
      <OEH_POSTAL_CODE  xsi:nil="true"/>
      <OEH_COUNTRY  xsi:nil="true"/>

      <ORDER_TBL_TYPE>
        <ORDER_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
        <OLevel1>2333</OLevel1>
        <OLevel2>344</OLevel2>
        <OLevel3>O</OLevel3>
          <PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>95678</PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>
          <TOTAL_ORDER_GROSSWEIGHT>345</TOTAL_ORDER_GROSSWEIGHT>
          <TOTAL_ORDER_SHIPQTY>32</TOTAL_ORDER_SHIPQTY>

          <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE>
            <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
              <!-- unbounded -->

              <ILevel1>2333</ILevel1>
              <ILevel2>2333</ILevel2>
              <ILevel3>2333</ILevel3>
              <PALLET_NUMBER>4546</PALLET_NUMBER>
              <CARTON_NUMBER>344235</CARTON_NUMBER>
              <WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>346788</WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>
              <FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>243546</FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>
              <VENDOR_NUM>344677</VENDOR_NUM>
              <ITEM>50116</ITEM>
              <CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>034138102008</CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>
            </ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>

            <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
            <ILevel1>2333</ILevel1>
              <ILevel2>2333</ILevel2>
              <ILevel3>2333</ILevel3>
              <PALLET_NUMBER>4546</PALLET_NUMBER>
              <CARTON_NUMBER>344235</CARTON_NUMBER>
              <WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>346788</WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>
              <FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>243546</FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>
              <VENDOR_NUM>344677</VENDOR_NUM>
              <ITEM>50116</ITEM>
              <CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>034138102008</CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>
            </ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>





          </ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE>
        </ORDER_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>

        <!-- 2 nd Order -->

      </ORDER_TBL_TYPE>
    </OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL_ITEM>
  </OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL>
</OutputParameters>
```

1)There is a multiple `<ORDER_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>` .

2)Inside `<ORDER_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>` multiple `<ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>` are present.

3)for each iteration we need a sequence of number assigned to the below showed elements and condition is also there if previous  = current  ignore level1,2,3 elements and directly pass ITEM value.

output:

```
    <OutputParameters>

  <OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL>
    <OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL_ITEM>
    <SLevel1>1</SLevel1>
    <SLevel1>S</SLevel1>
      <DELIVERY_ID>3335</DELIVERY_ID>
      <ORDER_SHIP_CODE_EXT>445</ORDER_SHIP_CODE_EXT>
      <CUSTOMER_NUMBER>4838</CUSTOMER_NUMBER>
      <OEH_POSTAL_CODE  xsi:nil="true"/>
      <OEH_COUNTRY  xsi:nil="true"/>

      <ORDER_TBL_TYPE>
        <ORDER_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
          <!-- unbounded -->
          <OLevel1>2</OLevel1>
        <OLevel2>1</OLevel2>
        <OLevel3>O</OLevel3>
          <PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>44342</PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>
          <!-- assign sequnce number starts from 2 -->
          <DELIVERY_ID>133232</DELIVERY_ID>
          <!-- hard code value as 1 -->
          <TOTAL_ORDER_GROSSWEIGHT>42323C</TOTAL_ORDER_GROSSWEIGHT>
          <!-- hard code value as C -->
          <TOTAL_ORDER_SHIPQTY>32</TOTAL_ORDER_SHIPQTY>

          <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE>

              <!-- unbounded -->



            <!-- The UniqueID is the temporary variable.PALLET_NUMBER is coming from input.

if PALLET_NUMBER!=NULL then

UniqueID=substring (PALLET_NUMBER, 10)

if PALLET_NUMBER =NULL then

UniqueID=substring (CARTON_NUMBER, 7) -->

<!-- Condition here If previous UniqueID != current UniqueID  and PALLET_NUMBER!=NULL  then-->IF TRUE
<ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>

              <ILevel1>3</ILevel1>
               <!-- assign sequnce number starts from 3 -->
              <ILevel2>2</ILevel2>
               <!-- assign sequnce number of <Olevel1> -->
              <ILevel3>T</ILevel3>
              <!-- hard code value as T-->
              <PALLET_NUMBER>45463456788899432445</PALLET_NUMBER>
              <CARTON_NUMBER>344235</CARTON_NUMBER>
              <WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>3y4</WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>

              <FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>442</FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>

              <VENDOR_NUM>C4466I</VENDOR_NUM>

              <ITEM>50116</ITEM>
              <CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>034138102008</CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>
            </ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>

            <!-- Condition here If previous UniqueID != current UniqueID  and PALLET_NUMBER =NULL  then-->iF TRUE
            <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
            <ILevel1>4</ILevel1>
               <!-- assign sequnce number increment -->
              <ILevel2>2</ILevel2>
               <!-- assign sequnce number of <Olevel1> -->
              <ILevel3>P</ILevel3>
              <!-- hard code value as T-->
              <PALLET_NUMBER></PALLET_NUMBER>
              <CARTON_NUMBER>344235</CARTON_NUMBER>
              <WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>3y4</WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>

              <FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>442</FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>

              <VENDOR_NUM>C4466I</VENDOR_NUM>

              <ITEM>50116</ITEM>
              <CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>034138102008</CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>
            </ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>



            <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
            <ILevel1>5</ILevel1>
               <!-- assign sequnce number increment -->
              <ILevel2>4</ILevel2>
               <!-- if T Level is true then <ILevel2> of T level 
               if P Level is true then <ILevel2> of P level 
               -->
              <ILevel3>I</ILevel3>
              <!-- hard code value as I-->
              <PALLET_NUMBER></PALLET_NUMBER>
              <CARTON_NUMBER>344235</CARTON_NUMBER>
              <WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>3y4</WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>

              <FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>442</FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>

              <VENDOR_NUM>C4466I</VENDOR_NUM>

              <ITEM>50116</ITEM>
              <CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>034138102008</CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>
            </ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>



<!-- Condition here If previous UniqueID != current UniqueID  and PALLET_NUMBER!=NULL  then-->IF FALSE

            < NO LOOP HERE FOR T LEVEL>



            <!-- Condition here If previous UniqueID != current UniqueID  and PALLET_NUMBER =NULL  then-->iF TRUE
            <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
            <ILevel1>6</ILevel1>
              <ILevel2>2</ILevel2>
              <ILevel3>P</ILevel3>
              <WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>685858</WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>
              <FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>87899</FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>
              <VENDOR_NUM>457482</VENDOR_NUM>
              <ITEM>50119</ITEM>
              <CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>034138102008</CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>
            </ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>


            <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
            <ILevel1>7</ILevel1>
              <ILevel2>6</ILevel2>
              <ILevel3>I</ILevel3>
              <WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>685858</WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>
              <FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>87899</FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>
              <VENDOR_NUM>457482</VENDOR_NUM>
              <ITEM>50119</ITEM>
              <CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>034138102008</CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>
            </ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>

</ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE>

        </ORDER_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>

        <!-- 2 nd Order -->


      </ORDER_TBL_TYPE>
    </OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL_ITEM>
  </OUT_SHIPMENT_TB
```

L>

Comment: Requirement #3 is difficult to understand. Also, you asked for help on the logic. Are you asking someone to write the code for you? What XSLT have you tried, and what was the result?

Comment: Thank you for fully clarifying the question this time. Could you tell us which XSLT processor you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL_ITEM | 
                       ORDER_TBL_TYPE_ITEM[1] | 
                       ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM[1]">
    <xsl:param name="currentSequenceNo" select="0" />

    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="iterate">
      <xsl:with-param name="currentSequenceNo" select="$currentSequenceNo" />
      <xsl:with-param name="parentSequenceNo" select="$currentSequenceNo" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ORDER_TBL_TYPE_ITEM | ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM" />

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="iterate">
    <xsl:param name="currentSequenceNo" />
    <xsl:param name="parentSequenceNo" />

    <xsl:variable name="differentFromPreviousStr">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="different" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="differentFromPrevious"
                  select="$differentFromPreviousStr = 'true'" />
    <xsl:variable name="thisSequenceNo"
                  select="$currentSequenceNo + $differentFromPrevious" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[$differentFromPrevious or position() &gt; 3]">
        <xsl:with-param name="currentSequenceNo" select="$thisSequenceNo" />
        <xsl:with-param name="parentSequenceNo" select="$parentSequenceNo" />
        <xsl:with-param name="code">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="code" />
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>

    <xsl:variable name="childSequenceCount">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="childSequence" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]
                                     [name() = name(current())]"
                         mode="iterate">
      <xsl:with-param name="currentSequenceNo"
                      select="$thisSequenceNo + $childSequenceCount" />
      <xsl:with-param name="parentSequenceNo" select="$parentSequenceNo" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="different">
    <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM" mode="different">
    <xsl:value-of
         select="not(ITEM = preceding-sibling::ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM[1]/ITEM)" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="childSequence">
    <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ORDER_TBL_TYPE_ITEM" mode="childSequence">
    <xsl:value-of
       select="count(ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE/ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM[not(
                              ITEM = 
                               preceding-sibling::ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM[1]/ITEM
                                            )])" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL_ITEM" mode="code">
    <xsl:text>E</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ORDER_TBL_TYPE_ITEM" mode="code">
    <xsl:text>C</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM" mode="code">
    <xsl:text>CI</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL | ORDER_TBL_TYPE | ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE">
    <xsl:param name="currentSequenceNo" select="0" />
    <xsl:param name="parentSequenceNo" />

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name ="currentSequenceNo" select="$currentSequenceNo" />
        <xsl:with-param name="parentSequenceNo" select="$parentSequenceNo" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()[self::OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL_ITEM or 
                              self::ORDER_TBL_TYPE_ITEM or
                              self::ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM]/*[1]">
    <xsl:param name="currentSequenceNo" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$currentSequenceNo"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()[self::ORDER_TBL_TYPE_ITEM or
                              self::ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM]/*[2]">
    <xsl:param name="parentSequenceNo" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$parentSequenceNo" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL_ITEM/*[2] | 
                       node()[self::ORDER_TBL_TYPE_ITEM or
                              self::ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM]/*[3]">
    <xsl:param name="code" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$code" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<OutputParameters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL>
    <OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL_ITEM>
      <DELIVERY_ID>1</DELIVERY_ID>
      <ORDER_SHIP_CODE_EXT>E</ORDER_SHIP_CODE_EXT>
      <CUSTOMER_NUMBER>4838</CUSTOMER_NUMBER>
      <OEH_POSTAL_CODE xsi:nil="true" />
      <OEH_COUNTRY xsi:nil="true" />
      <ORDER_TBL_TYPE>
        <ORDER_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
          <PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>2</PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>
          <TOTAL_ORDER_GROSSWEIGHT>1</TOTAL_ORDER_GROSSWEIGHT>
          <TOTAL_ORDER_SHIPQTY>C</TOTAL_ORDER_SHIPQTY>
          <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE>
            <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
              <WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>3</WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>
              <FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>2</FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>
              <VENDOR_NUM>CI</VENDOR_NUM>
              <ITEM>50116</ITEM>
              <CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>034138102008</CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>
            </ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
            <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
              <ITEM>50116</ITEM>
              <CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>034138102008</CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>
            </ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
            <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
              <WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>4</WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>
              <FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>2</FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>
              <VENDOR_NUM>CI</VENDOR_NUM>
              <ITEM>6435</ITEM>
              <CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>034138102008</CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>
            </ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
          </ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE>
        </ORDER_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
        <ORDER_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
          <PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>5</PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>
          <DELIVERY_ID>1</DELIVERY_ID>
          <TOTAL_ORDER_GROSSWEIGHT>C</TOTAL_ORDER_GROSSWEIGHT>
          <TOTAL_ORDER_SHIPQTY>32</TOTAL_ORDER_SHIPQTY>
          <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE>
            <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
              <WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>6</WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>
              <FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>5</FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>
              <VENDOR_NUM>CI</VENDOR_NUM>
              <ITEM>50119</ITEM>
              <CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>034138102008</CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>
            </ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
            <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
              <WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>7</WEB_TRANSACTION_ID>
              <FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>5</FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE_INT>
              <VENDOR_NUM>CI</VENDOR_NUM>
              <ITEM>87554</ITEM>
              <CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>034138102008</CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>
            </ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
            <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
              <ITEM>87554</ITEM>
              <CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>034138102008</CROSS_REFERENCE_UPC>
            </ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
          </ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE>
        </ORDER_TBL_TYPE_ITEM>
        <!-- 2 nd Order -->
      </ORDER_TBL_TYPE>
    </OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL_ITEM>
  </OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL>
</OutputParameters>
```

Comment: Yes  you are correct my sample xml is not actual xml.but the structure is same.The Logic should be generic.because here the sample input contains a 3 elements for each colors,colorItems,but in real there is a lot of elements are present.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply.if more elements comes inside the Colors and ColorItems the values are not coming in the output.

Comment: In that case, please provide an XML example with all of the elements that are going to be involved.

Comment: I can not add all the elements here(There is a lot of elements are there). I have added a sample input above now which is different of before.Please find the same.Kindly make this as generic.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, please try my modified answer above.

Comment: I already modified it to accept more values. Could you please test it out?

Comment: <Level2>1</Level2> is not coming properly.every time coming as same.This value should be the <color1></color1> sequence number.Please check.

Comment: Sorry about that. Should be fixed now.

Comment: sorry for the late!the below hard codedvalues not coming in the output.Pls check <code element="t">E</code>
    <code element="colors">C</code>
    <code element="colorItems">CI</code>

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by that? Are you saying that the `element2`, `color3` and `Level3` elements don't have those codes in them?

Comment: Ok, I've changed the implementation of the codes to an approach that should be more likely to work. Could you try it out?

Comment: Excellent,great job.Thanks a lot Rishe.

Comment: Rishe,I have added my exact input and output elements.can u please make this as required.

Comment: The out put structure you provided is not same as i provided.the second element <OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL> element is missed.can u please modify that,when u back.

Comment: Did you try the new version that I posted 4 minutes ago? `<OUT_SHIPMENT_TBL>` should be included.

Comment: yes it is working good,You are really gri8 Rishi.Thank u so much for ur support.

Comment: Hi Rishe there is another case here.If prvs Uniq Id = Current UniqId.I have pasted my new input and out put above.but here 3 levels are there and  two levels are condition based Plevel,Tlevel.

Comment: case1;
for each <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM> there is 3 levels are there but two of them are condition based 1)If previous UniqueID != current UniqueID and PALLET_NUMBER!=NULL true--> Tlevel ll come. 2) If previous UniqueID != current UniqueID and PALLET_NUMBER =NULL then-->Plevel ll come 3)default I Level –  
case2:
for each <ORDER_LINES_TBL_TYPE_ITEM> there is 3 levels are there butonly one has condition based 1)If previous UniqueID != current UniqueID and PALLET_NUMBER!=NULL true--> Tlevel ll come. 2) by defaultn Plevel ll come 3)default I Level.

Comment: for both these two cases can we  create a single xslt

Comment: @user2182390 Could you revert your question above and open your new inquiry as a new question?

Answer (score 0):

The conditional logic you're looking for is something like the following. I'm assuming here that the context node is a `<colorItems>` element.

```
<xsl:if test="color != preceding-sibling::colorItems[1]/color">
    ... process Level1, 2, 3 ...
</xsl:if>
<xsl:copy-of select="color" />
```

Comment: i have added my xslt above which is giving as almost same result.if we put the above condition we can ignore the level1,2,3 elements not the sequence numbers of that elements.please check.